# Changing zoom and LatLng through javascript (Google Maps JavaScript API v3)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am uusing the Google Maps JavaScript API v3 and have the following code to draw the initial map in JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={APIKey}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.507351, -0.127758)
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  } 
</script>
```

This draws the map fine onto my 'map-canvas' div on my web page. However, on a button click I'd like to change the position shown on the map, and too zoom in on this location. I have tried the following function from another question on Stack I found but nothing happens.

```
function changeMap () {
     map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644));
     map.setZoom(15);
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Your map variable is local to the initialize function.  It needs to be global if you are going to access it from an HTML "click" event.

```
// declare global map variable (outside of any functions)
var map = null;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 8,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.507351, -0.127758)
  };
  // initialize the map variable after the page "load" event fires
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}
```

Then this code will work (and not generate a javascript error stating that "map" is undefined).

```
function changeMap () {
   map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644));
   map.setZoom(15);
}
```